# parse a number represented as string and return array of numbers satisfying fibonacci relation

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given a number as string, return an array of it's digits satisfying `arr[i] = arr[i-1] + arr[i-2]`.

```
Example:-
'112358' = [1,1,2,3,5,8]
'1111213' = [11,1,12,13]
'1111223' = [1,11,12,23]
```

Comment: You will have to use backtracking with additional care of not including leading zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode of a solution is:

```
input: string with size n
output: string_array[m]

for i <- 2 to n 
     create all possible non-empty two splitting and 
     generate the sequence based on those two.
         if somewhere the generated sequence does not match with the input "string"
              try another splitting. 
         else:
              return the found splitting with all generated numbers.
```

The possible number of splitting a string with the size of `k` to two strings is `k-1`. Also, generating the sequence and check the last part of the string is `O(n)`. Therefore the time complexity of this algorithm is `sum_{k = 2}^n (k-1)n = n sum_{k = 2}^n (k-1) = O(n^3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both inputs are positive integers:

1. Determine the minimum digits possible in final number from the input length based on the 1,1 fib sequence.
2. Exhaustively check the length-3 solutions.
3. Note that after the first calculated value (3rd elt), the number of digits in adjacent numbers is either the same or differs by 1.
4. From min_digits to max_digits, check the two cases where the next-to-last number has the same digits or one fewer.

Note that all length 1-2 arrays are trivial solutions; a non-trivial solution will be at least length 3.

Note that exhaustively checking length 3 solutions isn't as bad as it sounds because one of the first two numbers has to have the same or one fewer digits than the 3rd number, limiting the search space.

Comment: Note that regardless of the input, the ratio of successive numbers will trend quickly towards (1+sqrt(5))/2